# Let $P(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2 x^2+a_3x^3+.......+a_nx^n$ and $P(1)=4$ and $P(5)=136$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, contest-math

Let $P(x)$ be a polynomial such that,
$$P(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2 x^2+a_3x^3+.......+a_nx^n,~~(a_i,n\in{Z^{\geq 0}})$$

$$ P(1)=4, P(5)=136$$

We have to find $P(3)$

This problem is harder than it looks (at least for me)

What I tried to do was
$$P(1)=a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3+.......+a_n=4$$ and $$P(5)=a_0+5a_1+25a_2 +125a_3+.......+a_n5^n$$

Let $P(1)=S$, and we take $a_0$ to the side of $S$ and multiply $(S-a_0)$ by $5$ and some cancellations. Simply it leads nowhere

Can I get some **Hints** on how to proceed?

Comment: $P(5) = 136$ gives an upper bound on which $a_i$ can be nonzero. From then on, there are very few options left to check.

Comment: @DanielFischer i think what you said is $a_i\le4$

Comment: Well $n$ cannot be more than $3$. You can start from there.

Comment: @Sayan please elaborate

Comment: set $a_n=0$ for all $n>1$. You have a straight line. Problem solved.

Comment: @Arjun if $n > 3$, $a_n5^n > 136$

Comment: @MikaelHelin $a_i>0$ and an integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The crucial observation comes from the fact the coefficients need to be in $\mathbb{Z}^{\geq 0}$.

$P(5) = 136$ can only be written in the following ways using powers of 5:

- $1 + (27)(5)$
- $1 + (22-5i)(5) + (i+1)(5^2)$ for $i = 0,1,2,3,4$
- $1 + (2)(5) + (1)(5^3)$

The only one that satisfies $P(1) = 4$ is the last one which is $P(x) = 1 + 2x + x^3$.

Therefore, $P(3) = 34$

Comment: then $a_2 = 0 \not \in \mathbb{Z}^+$?

Comment: answer matches! I did it slightly in a longer way but getting the same reasult

Comment: Please dont spoil questions if the OP asks for hints

Comment: @VIVID The problem would be impossible then

Comment: Either the OP is wrong about the domain of the coefficients or there doesn't exist such a polynomial...

Comment: @VIVID this is a national olymiad problem, no chances of being wrong

Comment: @Arjun It's very clear that it is wrong (or you have presented it wrong), else the answer cannot match, `The crucial observation comes from the fact the coefficients need to be in Z≥0`

Comment: @Arjun Then, could you provide any link to that olympiad paper for verification?

Comment: @VIVID, [page 12, question 30](https://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/olympiads/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/PRMO18_Question_Paper.pdf)

Comment: @Arjun It says non-negative which means $\mathbb{Z}^{\geq 0}$ and not $\mathbb{Z}^+$

Comment: @JohnWhite my bad, ill edit it

Comment: "The problem would be impossible then"  A good hint would be to consider what the remainders of $136$ are when divided by $5,25,125$ and $625$ and what that would say about the coefficients.  A second hint would be: is there any upper limit as to how large any of the coefficients might be.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly $n\le 3$ as $a_n5^n>136$ for $n\ge 4$ and $a_n\ge 1$. Since $P(5)=136$ this forces $a_3\le 1$. If $a_3=1$, clearly $a_2=0$ which forces $a_1=2$ and $a_0=1$. If $n=2$, as $a_0+a_1+a_2=4$, it is easy to check if all the $a_i$ are less than or equal to $4$, $P(5)=136$ is not achievable.

Answer (score 1):

Okay.... hints.

What is the remained of $136$ divided by $5,25, 125$ and $625$.

What does that say about $P(5) = \sum_{k=0}^n 5^k a_k$ and the values of $a_k$.

And $P(1) = \sum_{k=0}^n 1^k\cdot a_k$.  What does that say about how many non-zero values of $a_k$ there are and what their maximum values can be.

I hope with these hints that you not only can tell what $P(3)$ is, You can express $P(x)$ with absolute certainty.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Given that $P(1)=4$, I'm tempted to write $P(x) = x^{n_1}+x^{n_2}+x^{n_3}+x^{n_4}$ where $n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4$ are not necessarily distinct. Then using the fact $P(5)=136$ should be easier.